# Using couchdb for caching and scalability during high traffic periods

Tags: couchdb

We are working on a ticket sales e-commerce system. We often encounter high number of requests during on sale periods.

We use couchdb for caching purposes and a SQL server database as our data store.

One of the scenarios that we are dealing with is that if all the tickets for an event has been sold we would want to prevent any users from being able to buy them.

For us to be able to do this we would have to query the database on each sale which would be terrible.

My idea was to query the number of tickets for an event initially and store it in couchdb and on each sale we would decrement the couchdb records available tickets. When the couchdb record hits zero then we update the database and also prevent any users from buying any tickets for that event.

Could you validate my idea or if you have a better solution please elaborate.

Thank you

Comment: why do you think couchdb would be more efficient when it comes to subtracting 1 from an integer and storing it persistently than, say, mssql?

Comment: @IfLoop im just asking if it is or not and what would be the best way to approach this scenario, if you have an alternative approach please feel free to comment

Comment: Think a better fit for a scenario like this would be e.g. Redis or Aerospike, both having option to increment a value given a certain key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your approach. You can do it the way you described in your question and it would be perfectly fine. I personally prefer a different approach. Consider an event:

```
{
  "_id": 8e23456781b5567890,
  "event":"The rat pack symphony live from New york",
  "tickets" : 6000
}
```

Instead of decrementing this ticket counter whenever a new ticket is purchased we add a new ticket document.

```
{
  "_id": 7c665934r8206513,
   "sold_at":1409937545893,
   "event_id": "8e23456781b5567890",
    "sold_to":"some_one"
...other meta data

}
```

Then we create a view like:

#### Map

```
function(doc){
if(doc.event_id){
emit(doc.event_id,null);
  }
}
```

#### Reduce

```
_count
```

and then query this view with `key="event_id_for_which_you_want_tickets_sold"&reduce=true` to get the number of tickets sold.

**Why this way?**

Because it allows you to store more information about a ticket sold than when you just do a `counter -1`. Later you can run some kind of analysis on the tickets that you actually sold and it might help you understand your application better.

**Regarding caching**

While couchdb is certainly a good choice when it comes to caching but for this particular use case I think some thing like redis would be a far better alternative.

Comment: Event sourcing/logging is a nice concept. Don't know how important the "true" count is in this domain, but remember that CouchDB secondary-indexes will eventually consistent. Agreeing on looking at something like Aerospike or Redis instead.